# TraceId and SpanId are null in WebFilter even when it is registered after TraceWebFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth, opentracing

I'm currently using `2020.0.0` with Spring Boot `2.4.2` and registered a custom web filter that logs information from the request (Order is `webProperties.filterOrder + 1` -- so it should be registered after TraceWebFilter). For some reason, traceId and spanId are not in MDC (and therefore not logging).

WebFilter implementation:

```
class TraceWebFilter(
        private val webProperties: SleuthWebProperties,
        private val tracer: Tracer
): WebFilter, Ordered {
    override fun getOrder(): Int = webProperties.filterOrder + 1

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        logger.debug { "Building trace web filter" }

        return Mono.defer {
            MDC.put("Request-Method", exchange.request.method?.toString())
            MDC.put("Request-Path", exchange.request.path.toString())

            logger.info { tracer.currentSpan() }

            logger.info { ">> headers=${exchange.request.headers}" }
            logger.info { ">> method=${exchange.request.method}" }
            logger.info { ">> path=${exchange.request.path}" }

            exchange.response.beforeCommit {
                Mono.fromRunnable {
                    logger.info { "<< headers=${exchange.response.headers}" }
                    logger.info { "<< status=${exchange.response.rawStatusCode}" }
                }
            }

            chain.filter(exchange)
        }
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
app_1       | 2021-01-28 04:43:24.420 DEBUG [user-service,method=,path=,traceId=,spanId=] 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] o.s.c.s.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter    : Received a request to uri [/users]
app_1       | 2021-01-28 04:43:24.566 DEBUG [user-service,method=,path=,traceId=,spanId=] 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] o.s.c.s.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter    : Handled receive of span RealSpan(9b7383611e5a3bc2/9b7383611e5a3bc2)
app_1       | 2021-01-28 04:43:24.633 DEBUG [user-service,method=,path=,traceId=,spanId=] 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] c.p.p.components.tracing.TraceWebFilter  : Building trace web filter
app_1       | 2021-01-28 04:43:24.638  INFO [user-service,method=POST,path=/users,traceId=,spanId=] 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] c.p.p.components.tracing.TraceWebFilter  : null
app_1       | 2021-01-28 04:43:24.694  INFO [user-service,method=POST,path=/users,traceId=,spanId=] 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] c.p.p.components.tracing.TraceWebFilter  : >> headers=[content-type:"application/json", user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.26.8", accept:"*/*", cache-control:"no-cache", postman-token:"18d99e30-ce7a-4659-a2c1-21020d8bf2b5", host:"localhost:9100", accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br", connection:"keep-alive", content-length:"2"]
app_1       | 2021-01-28 04:43:24.699  INFO [user-service,method=POST,path=/users,traceId=,spanId=] 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] c.p.p.components.tracing.TraceWebFilter  : >> method=POST
app_1       | 2021-01-28 04:43:24.747  INFO [user-service,method=POST,path=/users,traceId=,spanId=] 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] c.p.p.components.tracing.TraceWebFilter  : >> path=/users
```

Please notice the following:

- traceId and spanId in the logs are null
- logged tracer.currentSpan in logs is null

Any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use MDC in Reactor world

Comment: MDC can be used in Reactor world. Just call Kotlin's withLoggingContext to set it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [`TraceWebFilter`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/2.2.x/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebFilter.java), you will see that it does not put anything into the `MDC` (`MDC` is basically a `ThreadLocal` and you are in an async event loop).

1. But it interacts with the `Tracer` that you can also inject into your filter and get the current Span from it: `tracer.currentSpan()` and from the `TraceContext` of the `Span` you can get the `traceId` and `spanId`.
2. Also, it puts the `Span` into the Exchange Attributes:

```java
this.exchange.getAttributes().put(TRACE_REQUEST_ATTR, span);
```

I recommend injecting the `Tracer` into your filter and getting the current `Span` from it.

Comment: I notice that by the time the Controller is executed, the traceId and spanId are already in the MDC. Is there a specific component that does this? Is there a way to add my custom webfilter after this?

Comment: I also tried injecting the `Tracer` and accessing `tracer.currentSpan()` and it returned null. Updated the question to reflect this.